# Selenium: PayPal Login process in Web Application

Tags: selenium, paypal, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

My application having Paypal as a payment option, while doing automation testing using Selenium Web Driver, the process flow goes on without any error but when flow navigate to Paypal login page  filling all the fields(username, password) and then click on login button, the `EXPECTED FLOW Is: page redirects to order confirm page, but the Paypal login page get refresh and stay on the page with empty fields`. I also checked it by increasing timeout seconds but nothing happens.
Below is my code:

```
@Test
    public void testAsdChannel(){
        for(RemoteWebDriver driver: drivers){
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            HomePage hPage = HomePage.navigateTo(driver, SERVER);
            ....
            AsdConfirmPage asdPage = asdChannelFlow.acceptOffer();
            asdChannelPage.paypalLogin("username", "pswd"); 
            Assert.assertEquals(asdConfirmPage.asdOrderConfirm(), "Your order has been received");
             }
    }
```

// Here below i am providing paypalLogin(String userName, String pswd) Method:

```
public void paypalLogin(String username, String password){
        paypalEmail.sendKeys(username); // 'paypalEmail'text field element on paypal login page
        paypalPswd.sendKeys(password); // 'paypalPswd' field element on same.
        paypalLoginBtn.submit(); // 'paypalLoginBtn' button element on same
    }
```

// And here are the elements paypalLoginBtn, paypalPswd, paypalEmail

```
    @FindBy(name = "email")
    WebElement paypalEmail;

    @FindBy(name = "password")
    WebElement paypalPassword;

    @FindBy(id = "loginButton")
    WebElement paypalLoginBtn;
```

Please suggest any remedy for this problem............thanks in advance.

Comment: At which **line** does it throw the exception?

Comment: this one: asdChannelPage.paypalLogin("username", "pswd"); and within 'paypalLogin' method. But I know the cause of exception. My query is the page not redirects to EXPECTED FLOW as give in my query description.

Comment: What driver and what version of that driver? What browser version do you have? What OS? What version of Selenium? Have you tried using different selectors to see if it works then? Can you copy/paste the *entire* exception here?

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011236/how-selenium-webdriver-locate-element-with-a-http-response-full-of-javascript